# How can I split these columns from my table only in certain rows?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm new to HTML and would like to create a table that looks like the one in this picture:

[image: Table image]

I have a close attempt, but some columns in the middle are merged unlike the table shown in the bottom of the picture. I want my code to have split columns like in that bottom table.

```html
<h6>↓ My Table ↓</h6>
<table border="3">
  <tr align="center">
    <th colspan="7">Element</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>I</th>
    <th>II</th>
    <th>III IV V</th>
    <th>VI</th>
    <th>VII</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Periyodik Element<br><center>Tablosu</center></td>
    <td>`&nbsp;`</td>
    <td>He</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Li</td>
    <td>Be</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Ne</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ne</td>
    <td>Mg</td>
    <td>Al</td>
    <td>Ar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>Ca</td>
    <td><center>Sc &nbsp;Ti &nbsp;V</center></td>
    <td>Ga</td>
    <td>Kr</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I want the table to be as in the picture, some rows not merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The setting you are looking for is the **`colspan` attribute**.

In `colspan`, you can specify how many columns wide a particular column should be. For example, in the cell with the text "Periodic Table of Elements", where you have correctly set the `rowspan` to be 3 rows high, you should also **set the `colspan` to be 3 columns wide**.

Any cell **that spans multiple columns in the image should be represented by multiple separate cells in the code**. So, instead of entering the "III, IV, and V" cells in one cell, you should enter them in three different cells. Please follow my example to understand the solution.

```html
<h6>↓ My Table ↓</h6>
<table border="3">
  <tr align="center">
    <th colspan="7">Element</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>I</th>
    <th>II</th>

    <!-- Added three separated column -->
    <th>III</th>
    <th>IV</th>
    <th>V</th>

    <th>VI</th>
    <th>VII</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #FFCBFF;">H</td> <!-- Added background-color -->

    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <!-- Set colspan (how many column is it) to 3 -->
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"> <!-- Added text-align instead of <center> -->
       <p style="margin: 0 4px;">Periyodik Element</p> <!-- Added <p> instead of <br> -->
       <p style="margin: 0 4px;">Tablosu</p> <!-- Added <p> instead of <br> -->
    </td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFDA7;">He</td> <!-- Added background-color -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Li</td>
    <td>Be</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFDA7;">Ne</td> <!-- Added background-color -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ne</td>
    <td>Mg</td>
    <td>Al</td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFDA7;">Ar</td> <!-- Added background-color -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>Ca</td>

    <!-- Added three separated column -->
    <td style="text-align: center;">Sc</td> <!-- Added text-align instead of <center> -->
    <td style="text-align: center;">Ti</td> <!-- Added text-align instead of <center> -->
    <td style="text-align: center;">V</td> <!-- Added text-align instead of <center> -->

    <td>Ga</td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFDA7;">Kr</td> <!-- Added background-color -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

### More information

[`<td>` colspan attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attributes) - MDN

**Use CSS for formatting (ex. `text-align: center;` or `display: block;` or `font-weight: bold;`)** instead of HTML elements (ex. `<center>`, `<br>`, `<strong>`, etc.)

[What's CSS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics)

[Use `class` for CSS formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) - MDN

Answer (score 0):

The borders are a bit tricky but `colspan` was required on your rowspan table cell.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.my-table {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 0.3rem white, /* white gap after table border=2 */
    0 0 0 0.35rem black, /* border before outer border */
    0 0 0 0.5rem white, /* white gap before outer border*/
    0 0 0 0.8rem #808080; /* outer border*/
}

.pink-cell {
  background: #ffcbff;
}

.yellow-cell {
  background: #ffff9e;
}
```

```html
<h6>↓ My Table ↓ </h6>
<table class="my-table" border="1" cellspacing="3">
  <tr align="center">
    <th colspan="7">Periyodik ElementTablosu</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>I</th>
    <th>II</th>
    <th>III</th>
    <th>IV</th>
    <th>V</th>
    <th>VI</th>
    <th>VII</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="pink-cell">H</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">
      <center>Periyodik ElementTablosu</center>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="yellow-cell">He</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Li</td>
    <td>Be</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td class="yellow-cell">Ne</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ne</td>
    <td>Mg</td>
    <td>Al</td>
    <td class="yellow-cell">Ar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>Ca</td>
    <td>
      <center>Sc</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>Ti</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>V</center>
    </td>
    <td>Ga</td>
    <td class="yellow-cell">Kr</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```